# in itcl we use a command called chain to use method from base class, is there any alternative way to use?

Tags: tcl, itcl

The use of chain command in itcl make the response for command very
   slow when i want to chain the whole class which was inherited, so is
   there any other way i can use the base class functions thank using
   the chain command in itcl?

```
itcl::class Toaster {
    variable crumbs 0
    method toast {nslices} {
        if {$crumbs > 50} {
            error "== FIRE! FIRE! =="
        }
        set crumbs [expr $crumbs+4*$nslices]
    }
    method clean {} {
        set crumbs 0
    }
}
itcl::class SmartToaster {
    inherit Toaster
    method toast {nslices} {
        if {$crumbs > 40} {
            clean
        }
        return [Toaster::toast $nslices]
    }
}

itcl::class SmartToaster {
    inherit Toaster
    method toast {nslices} {
        if {$crumbs > 40} {
            clean
        }
        return [chain $nslices]
    }
}
```

The above is the example, where they have used chain, but in my case
   the class "Toaster" which has huge lot many methods and procs,
   atleast 50 methods and 10 procs which is making chain to operate
   slower. so any alternative to this?

Comment: Which version of itcl is this?

Comment: @DonalFellows I am using tcl 8.4

Comment: Can i get any alternative for this?